# Using a heat gun to transfer toner onto DIY PCB?

Tags: pcb-fabrication, heat

Is it possible/practical to use a heat gun instead of an iron to transfer toner when making your own PCBs?  Can you get a uniform heat pattern without for a small board?  Is enough heat applied from the heat gun to actually transfer the toner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, so for anyone else looking at this, I tried it and it seems like you do need the pressure of the iron.  Heat gun is a no go.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience with iron-based toner transfer you really need to apply lots of pressure to get the toner to transfer properly. I tried lots of different techniques (>10 tries) before finding the correct paper, correct/sufficient pressure across the board was important.

I suggest you try with an iron first and then move on to heat guns. I'm interested in your findings.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a crazy idea I got, but...

Build your own little contraption consisting of two sheet of metal, say aluminum, and drill 4 wholes in the corners. Add some nuts and bolts through said wholes to apply pressure, and lastly apply heat. This could be with a big-ass heat gun, or even a (domestic) oven.

Report back with the results if you try it. :)

Comment: I think that you will have problems with getting even pressure distribution over the whole metal sheets. Some areas may get good contact while other may be loose.

Comment: I tried pretty much this.  To apply even pressure, I used some silicon rubber foam (about 1/4" thick) on either side of the board.  Then it went into the oven.  It worked OK, but not great.  You have to leave it in the oven a while for the heat to diffuse through the foam, which acts like an insulator.  But silicone can handle the heat.  It might work better with a thin silicone sheet instead.